# Javascript mask

Tags: javascript

How do you format a number to show 2 decimals in JavaScript?

Something along the lines of:
format(x,"9,999.99");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this :

```
x.toFixed(2);
```

or if you want to be sure it will work :

```
parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I had to use parseFloat first because JavaScript wasn't recognizing my numbers as numeric.

Answer (score 2):

```
var num = 3.14159;
var fixed = num.toFixed(2);
```

If you want the commas depending on the locale:

```
var localed = num.toLocaleString();
```

Combining both crudely:

```
var num = 3.14159;
var fixed = num.toFixed(2);
var fixednum = parseFloat(fixed);
var localedFixed = fixednum.toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.toFixed(2)`:

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/17443.asp

Note this will round your number:

```
var i = 23.778899;
alert(i.toFixed(2));
```

gives you

```
23.78
```

Comment: @crescentfresh, The question didn't specifically ask for it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are trying to do this to input or just for displaying text on the page. You can use the masked input plugin for jQuery if you are trying to format input.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I don't think this is what he wanted, I suppose psenn wants to specify the number of decimals